# How to read the specific content from web page & store in Excel sheet through Web driver

Tags: java, selenium

We have an application which display a table just like below

```
Group ID       Group Name             Organization ID  Organization Type User Limit    
GP00000517001  SIPtest Site hostpool  SIP00000517      Enterprise        10000     
GP8566747001   SIT mars test SIP te   SIP8566747       Enterprise        10000
```

We have around 500 records are there in the same row for Group ID,
I wants to read only the Group ID from this page & store in Excel sheet, How can i do this? please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

```
I recommend you to use [HtmlParser][1] libs to read page. 
because it will help you to identify your table content using ID OR Tag Name.
Jsoup example-
         String url = "http://www.google.com/";
         Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
         String question = document.select("#_eEe").text();

     then use [Apache POI][2] to save data to excel sheet..

     HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
     HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sample");
     Row row = sheet.createRow(1);           
     Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
     cell.setCellValue("Sample");
     FileOutputStream out =  new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\new.xls"));
     workbook.write(out);
     out.close();

      [1]: http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/
      [2]: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html
```